# Visibile App Windows Minimize when I click on dock icons

Tags: macos

So if i have "Program A" open and click on "Program B"... "Pro A" windows minimize and i get "Program B"... if i click on the "Prog A" dock icon... "Prog B" windows minimize!  Please help.  I have tried changing the Mission Control settings but this is infuriating.

Answer (score 1):

So what happened was.  In Onyx I mistook "Single Application Mode" in the Parameters/Dock area as the setting to make the windows minimize to the dock icon.  This option only allows one application to be viewed at a time.

Comment: Onyx is a program for OSX that goes under the hood of the OS a bit... more for cleaning and resetting permissions and changing some options... for example you can change your boot screen in Oynx.  Good program and anything you do is easy to revert back.